# Removing a ProgessIndicator when no longer needed

Tags: gui-construction

I have a progress indicator in my *Mathematica* notebook that I update as various calculations are performed:

```
indicator = ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[progress]];
```

I would like to figure out how to remove the indicator when the calculations are complete or in the case above when

```
progress == 1
```

I’ve looked through the documentation and can’t seem to find a good way to do this.

Comment: Does the second example in the `Basic Examples` section of [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Monitor.html) in the docs look useful?

Comment: Good to know about Monitor but that didn’t help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just not draw it if the progress goal is achieved:

```
Dynamic[
 x = Clock[3];
 If[x < 1,
  ProgressIndicator[x],
  Sequence[]
  ]
 ]
```

`Sequence` can be "" or whatever is appropriate in your application.

Comment: All the answers are good… I didn’t explain my situation fully. Hence I will chose the first answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite unclear where that element is, so maybe this approach will fit you needs:

```
progress := Clock[1, 1, 1];

nb = CreatePalette[DynamicWrapper[
                     ProgressIndicator@Dynamic@progress, 
                     If[progress == 1, NotebookClose@nb], UpdateInterval -> 1]
      ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an inelegant way of getting rid of progress indicators at the end of a calculation, while leaving other results alone:

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[]; (*The current notebook object.*)
SelectionMove[nb, Previous, GeneratedCell]; (*Select ALL cells just generated ...*)
sc = SelectedCells[]; (*... and get them.*)
MapIndexed[ (*Map over them, and...*)
  (nr = ToString[NotebookRead[#1]]; (*... get a String version.*)
  If[Not[StringFreeQ[nr, "ProgressIndicator"]],(*Does it have "ProgressIndicator"?*)
    NotebookDelete[sc[[#2[[1]]]]] (*If so, delete the cell.*)
    ]
  )&, sc];

SelectionMove[nb, After, Cell]; (*Finally, put the selection back where it belongs.*)
```

Better late than never! I hope this helps. Obviously, the code could also be invoked from 'progress' with an 'If' statement.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try such code:

```
trig = True;

pi = Dynamic[If[trig, ProgressIndicator[0.5], ""]];

pi
```

If **trig** is True, then ProgressIndicator is visible, otherwise it is not..

Playing with value of **trig** you can dynamically change the state of any visible elements.